# CRTP vs template specialization and tag dispatching

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out the advantages and disadvantages of the CRTP idiom as opposed to template specialization. Let's say I want to create a "Renderer" class, and the renderer will either be implemented using "Vulkan" or "OpenGL".

With CRTP:

```
template <typename T>
class Renderer
{
public:
    void draw(Shape s) { static_cast<T*>(this)->drawImpl(s); };
};

class VulkanRenderer : public Renderer<VulkanRenderer>
{
public:
    void drawImpl(Shape s) { /* Vulkan implementation */};
};

class OpenGLRenderer : public Renderer<OpenGLRenderer>
{
public:
    void drawImpl(Shape s) { /* OpenGL implementation */ };
};
```

With template specialization and class tags:

```
class Vulkan;
class OpenGL;

template<typename T>
class Renderer
{
public:
    Renderer() { assert(false, "Type not support"); }
    void draw(Shape s);
};

template<>
class Renderer<Vulkan>
{
public:
    void draw(Shape s) { /* Vulkan implementation */ };
};

template<>
class Renderer<OpenGL>
{
public:
    void draw(Shape s) { /* OpenGL implementation */ };
};
```

Are there certain advantages of the one method over the other? Are there certain things I can do with the one that I won't be able to do with the other? Are there any alternatives for static polymorphism techniques?

Also, is there any advantage to either of these methods of simply defining separate classes such as "VulkanRenderer" and "OpenGLRenderer". Also, would concepts perhaps not be a better way that both of these?

Comment: 1) Suppose `draw` calls `drawImpl` and `drawImpl2` in the implementation. How would you do that in the second approach? 2) `static_assert(false);` makes your program ill-formed.

Comment: @Evg I've changed it to just a normal assert. But how would 1) work for the CRTP option?

Comment: You just do `static_cast<T*>(this)->drawImpl(s); static_cast<T*>(this)->drawImpl2(s);`. CRTP allows you to write non-trivial function bodies, not just simple call forwardings.

Comment: I would normally recommend the standard inheritance-with-virtual-functions approach over either of those. The benefits you draw from then are often imaginary, but the drawbacks are real. If you know that the standard approach is insufficient and you can demonstrate it with profiling results or other such data, then and only then consider alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CRTP, you can put any shared code/types/constants etc. into the base template, supporting both implementations.  If you don't have things to share, there's no point using CRTP.  It does have the usually easily managed downside that dynamically created derived objects risk accidental or careless deletion via a base class pointer, causing undefined behaviour.

With the class tags, the only difference from having two unrelated classes is that it's easier to constrain other templates to require some kind of Renderer (i.e. `template <typename ARenderer> void f(Renderer<ARenderer>& r);`), rather than having a requirement on unrelated classes like `std::is_same_v<T, OpenGLRenderer> || std::is_same_v<T, VulcanRenderer>` - not much utility.  If the renderers really have nothing in common except the semantics of their interface, then this is an option.

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question! Do you have any recommendations on other methods? Essentially,  the renderers might share some implementation, there also might be implementation specific functions, but only one will be used at a time, and I would like the caller to be unaware of which they are using except at initialization (using potentially a global define and a typedef)

Comment: @GaryAllen: another approach occasionally worth considering is having different namespaces for each renderer - then by `using` the desired namespace, you can pick up a whole slew of types, classes, templates, functions, constants etc. - it's clean and simple if you're just using one of the namespaces based on a global define.  A downside is that it may be more tedious to write tests that will test first the OpenGl then Vulcan renderers (or vice versa), whereas with either template approach you mentioned you can trivially instantiate and run two versions of the test classes or functions.